# Ajax não funciona com Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Olá, tenho o seguinte código, onde o Modal Bootstrap abre a partir de uma pesquisa no BD quando eu clico em um item da lista retornada:

```html
<input type="text" name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa">
<table class="resultado">
</table>
```

Até ai tudo bem, ele retorna os valores corretamente, abre o Modal com o ID correto, porem quando eu clico no botão para executar, ele executa a função somente com o primeiro item da coluna ID do BD, ou seja, funciona somente com ID "1", os demais ID ele não retorna o valor em conteúdo.

```js
function reg_prod() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../_php/nova_entrega_reg_prod.php",
    data: {
      produto: $('#id').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#conteudo').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $qry['id']?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Titulo</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body" style="white-space: normal;">
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="id" value="<?php echo $qry['id']?>">
   </div>
      
   <div id="conteudo">Teste</div>
      
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
   <button type="button" onClick="reg_prod()" class="btn btn-success">Registrar</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Aqui em conteúdo que ele deveria retornar, nesse caso, o mesmo ID que ele abriu a MODAL

```html
<?php
$produto = $_POST['produto'];

echo $produto;
?>
```

Alguém sabe porque isso acontece?

Comment: Que botão "Executar" seria esse?

Comment: o botao que executa a função ->  <button type="button" onClick="reg_prod()" class="btn btn-success">Registrar</button>

Comment: Nessa parte aqui `value="<?php echo $qry['id']?>"` o `id` não muda...

Comment: O ajax está pegando esse `id` que nunca muda...

Comment: é que se vc for ver, esse trecho está dentro do modal, que vai abrir de acordo com o ID, então, cada id que eu abro com o modal, ele aparece no input, o id relacionado ao modal. só que ao executar a função, ele só funciona quando eu abro o modal referente ao ID 1..

Comment: Sim. MAs esse id está vindo do PHP, e vc só está alterando a div conteúdo... o id do input `name="nome"` vai ser sempre o mesmo.

Comment: quando eu abro o modal do ID 2, ele aparece la no input, ID 2, porem parece que o ajax não executa, como eu poderia fazer o ajax pegar o valor do input ID referente ao modal aberto? é possível?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75627/discussion-between-dvd-and-thiagokoller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É preciso pegar o `id` de cada `input` da respectiva modal. Da forma que está fazendo, vai sempre pegar o `id` da primeira modal que encontrar, e ainda tem que definir `id`s diferentes para cada coisa. O que está fazendo é repetir `id`s, o que é incorreto. Um `id` deve ser único na mesma página.

Altere os `id`s dos elementos usando o valor do PHP:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="id<?php echo $qry['id']?>" value="<?php echo $qry['id']?>">
```

> Já que você quer passar o valor do campo que é o próprio `id`, nem
>   precisa do atributo `id="id"`, ficando assim:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $qry['id']?>">
```

e na `div` coloque também o `id` do PHP...

```
<div id="conteudo<?php echo $qry['id']?>">Teste</div>
```

Passe o `id` como parâmetro para o Ajax no `onclick`:

```
<button type="button" onClick="reg_prod('<?php echo $qry['id']?>')" class="btn btn-success">Registrar</button>
```

E altere a função do Ajax para receber e enviar o `id`:

```
function reg_prod(i) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../_php/nova_entrega_reg_prod.php",
    data: {
      produto: i,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#conteudo'+i).html(data);
    }
  });
}
```